# handlebar partial not displaying in materialize card?

Tags: handlebars.js

My group is making a chore chart project. we are stuck on how to get our partial(which is a dropdown with hardcoded users) to display in a card. we have displayed our dropdown above the card to see functionality, which it works. but when we place partial in card it does not...

Comment: You will make it much easier for others to help you if you provide the relevant code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.